How can I serve assets from an NPM module in an Astro project?
I'm looking for an automated way - not manually copying files into /public to serve assets that are inside an NPM module. This is quite a common pattern so I would have thought it would be straighforward - but I haven't seen anything in the docs thats suggests how.
I would have expected you could configure multiple sources for the /public folder but that doesn't seem to be the case.
The only other option I can think of would be using a build tool to copy the files across but I'm not sure where this would go - maybe astro.config.mjs?
I'm looking for the most simple 'out-of-the-box' solution e.g. not using dependencies if at all possible.

when you import a file from a npm module, it will be bundled by Astro, regardless whether it's a JavaScript, JSON, CSS file or similar (astro is using vite under the hood). what file exactly do you wish to use and where/how?

@mb21 Ah interesting, I think for my use-case that might work but its not guaranteed - basically I am using an NPM library of widgets that expects assets to be served from a particular folder e.g. /assets/images - the JS is supplied minified so hopefully there aren't any hardcoded paths in there

most such libraries have documentation explaining how they're supposed to be used in a setup with a bundler (such as astro with vite)
